# ASP.NET MVC: Razor <tr> do not match close tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model filled with List model and I want to use `foreach` loop to display it ,but ....my html looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-0"><img src="~/images/temp/1.png"></td>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-1"><img src="~/images/temp/2.png"></td>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-2"><img src="~/images/temp/4.png"></td>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-3"><img src="~/images/temp/3.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-11"><img src="~/images/temp/7.png"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </td>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-4"><img src="~/images/temp/5.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-10"><img src="~/images/temp/1.png"></td>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-5"><img src="~/images/temp/6.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-9"><img src="~/images/temp/3.png"></td>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-8"><img src="~/images/temp/6.png"></td>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-7"><img src="~/images/temp/8.png"></td>
    <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-6"><img src="~/images/temp/7.png"></td>
</tr>
```

`lottery-unit lottery-unit-0` to `lottery-unit lottery-unit-11` is eleven dto I want to display,and the `tr` is not fixed.
and if I use razor to write it like this :

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Order >= 0 && item.Order <= 3)
    {
        if (item.Order == 0)
        {
            <tr>                                                
        }
        <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-0"><img src="~/images/temp/1.png"></td>
        @if(item.Order == 3)
        {
            </tr>
        }
    }
```

The above will make some errors. Then how to write the correct code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `@` in front of the `foreach` and also add [`@:`](http://razorcheatsheet.com/#csharp) in front of the `<tr>` and `</tr>` inside the `if` statements. Your code should be like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Order >= 0 && item.Order <= 3)
    {
        if (item.Order == 0)
        {
            @:<tr>
        }
        <td class="lottery-unit lottery-unit-0"><img src="~/images/temp/1.png"></td>
        if (item.Order == 3)
        {
             @:</tr>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `<text>` for multiline content.